# How To ReShape a Numpy Array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a `numpy array` of images with the shape of `(5879,)`. Inside every index of the numpy array, I have the Pixels of the image with a shape of `(640,640,3)`.
I want to reshape the complete array in such a way that the shape of the numpy array becomes `(5879,640,640,3)`.

Comment: try `array.ravel().reshape((5879,640,640,3))`

Comment: Seems like you need `np.stack`.

Comment: What's the dtype of the original array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check, whether below code works for you or not

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([5879])
b.shape

output (1,)

a = np.array([[640],[640],[3]])
a = a.reshape((a.shape[0], 1))
a.shape

output (3, 1)

c = np.concatenate((a,b[:,None]),axis=0)
c.shape

Output:
(4, 1) 

np.concatenate((a,b[:,None]),axis=0)

output 
array([[ 640],
   [ 640],
   [   3],
   [5879]])
```

Comment: you can reshape c to (1, 4) using c = c.reshape((1,c.shape[0]))

Answer (score 0):

You want to stack your images along the first axis, into a 4D array. However, your images are all 3D.
So, first you need to [add a leading singleton dimension](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) to all images, and then to [concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) them along this axis:

```
imgs = [i_[None, ...] for i_ in orig_images]  # add singleton dim to all images
x = np.concatenate(imgs, axis=0)  # stack along the first axis
```

**Edit:**
Based on [Mad Phyiscist's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53606277/how-to-reshape-a-numpy-array-in-python/53607214?noredirect=1#comment94076132_53607214), it seems like using [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack) is more appropriate here: `np.stack` takes care of adding the leading singleton dimension for you:

```
x = np.stack(orig_images, axis=0)
```

Comment: Seems like overkill. Probably better to stack instead of concatenating.

Comment: I don't think it's overkill.  `stack` does the same thing, just hiding it in an function call.  It's convenient, but it's also a good idea to know how to use `concatenate` directly.